# Show that $G=N_1 N_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let p be a prime number and $N_1 , N_2 \triangleleft G   $ with $N_1 \cap N_2 ={e} $, where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are non trivial subgroups of G, $[G:N_1]=[G: N_2]=p$.

Show that $G=N_1 N_2$

I'm stuck on how to do this, I'm thinking from $[G: N_1]=[G: N_2]=p$, we have the quotient groups of each of these have order p, but i'm not really sure if this shows anything. If we can show that the order of $N_1 N_2$ is equal to G will this suffice? has anyone got any idea how to progress with this problem?

Comment: Perhaps $N_1$ and $N_2$ are maximal subgroups of $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first like to point out that you mean $[G:N_1]$ and $[G:N_2]$ ($[G,N_1]$ does mean something else, so be careful).

So you don't actually need $[G:N_2]=p$. My strong hint is to show $N_1<N_1N_2\le G$ and compute $[G:N_1N_2]$.

Comment: Is  $[G: N_1 N_2]=p^2$?

Comment: No, use $[G:N_1]=[G:N_1N_2][N_1N_2:N_1]$

Comment: Oh so is it equal to 1 and then because of this it means that the only cosets in $|G/N_1 N_2|$ are those corresponding to the identity, so there are no elements in G not in $N_1$ and $N_2$? hence G has order p^2?

Comment: It does equal 1. It follows then that no element of $G$ lies outside $N_1N_2$. That is $G=N_1N_2$ which you can prove has order $p^2$

Comment: How do we work out what the order of $[N_1 N_2: N_1]$ is? I got it to just be equivalent to $|N_2|$, but i'm not sure how we know what this is?

Comment: The equality in my first comment implies it divides $p$. It can't be 1, so must be $p$

Comment: @RobertChamberlain How do you conclude that $N_1N_2$ has order $p^2$ (in your previous comment above)? I see nothing that would imply this; indeed it might even have infinite order.

Comment: $N_1$ and $N_2$ are given as normal subgroups of $G$. Notice $N_1\cong G/N_2$ so $|N_1N_2|=|N_1N_2:N_1||N_1|=|N_1N_2:N_1||N_1N_2:N_2|=p^2$

Comment: Can we in fact assume that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal subgroups? That isn't given and doesn't appear to follow from the other assumptions. It's certainly possible to have $HK = G$ even if neither $H$ nor $K$ are normal.

Comment: I have just noticed the question says $N_1N_2 \triangleleft G$ which I misread as $N_1,N_2 \triangleleft G$, so no it is not given that they are normal. However, in proving $G=N_1N_2$ I use only the fact $N_1$ and $N_2$ are subgroups, which is given. Then as $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$ the map $N_1\to G/N_2$ (cosets of $N_2$, not immediately seen to be a group) defined by $x\mapsto xN_2$ is injective and, as $G=N_1N_2$, surjective. Hence $|N_1|=|G:N_2|$. Normality then cos for example from the fact all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Ah, nice argument!

Comment: Sorry that was an typo in the question it was meant to be what you originally thought! I have edited it!